# Keras cant slice model by layer used in loss without outputting it

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tf.keras

I got two outputs, and only one of them (`x1`) is output of model. I want to get 2nd (`x2`) also, but it is used in loss only.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def myloss2(sigma):
    gtsigma = 0.5
    kl = sigma / gtsigma

    def temp(gt, pr):
        return kl + (gtsigma ** 2 + (pr - gt) ** 2) / (2 * sigma ** 2) - 0.5

    return temp

def buildmodel2():
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10,))
    x1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')(inputs)
    x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(inputs)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, x1)
    model.compile(loss=myloss2(x2), optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
    return model
```

And now i cant see `x2` layer in `model2.summary()` so i cant slice my model to get its output.
Yes, i can do like this:

```
def myloss(data):
    pr, sigma, gt = data
    gtsigma = 0.5
    kl = sigma / gtsigma
    return kl + (gtsigma ** 2 + (pr - gt) ** 2) / (2 * sigma ** 2) - 0.5

def buildmodel():
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10,))
    gt = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10,))
    x1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')(inputs)
    x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(inputs)
    out = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(myloss)([x1, x2, gt])
    model = tf.keras.Model([inputs, gt], out)
    model.compile(loss=lambda a, b: b, optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
    return model
```

But for me its not comfortable to use model like this.
Are there any other ways?

Comment: I'm confused about your loss function. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Actually, its KL loss, but without log on the first term.

Comment: So I'm assuming `lambda a, b: b` is just a placeholder, because that's definitely not KL loss.

Comment: No, its just a function like loss(y_gt,y_pr),where y_pr is KL loss, so im just returning its value and minimizing it ( 'out' variable is KL loss )